# Cannot cd into Application Support on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: mac, terminal

I'm having a strange problem this morning

I'm trying to `cd` into the "Application Support" directory on my Mac, using the following command:

```
cd '~/Library/Application Support'
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be working as expected and I get this message:

```
-bash: cd: /Users/purinkle/Library/Application: Not a directory
```

Even trying `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/` doesn't work

Comment: Try running a shell with default state using `bash --noprofile --norc` and try running the cd command in that shell. If it works, then something in your shell customization is the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Both single quotes and double quotes prevent tilde expansion.

Any of these should work though:

- `cd ~/'Library/Application Support/'`
- `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/`
- `cd "$HOME/Library/Application Support/"`

Comment: I've tried all three and I've even tried `cd "/Users/purinkle/Library/Application Support/"`, but to no avail

Comment: Tyr single quote, not --> "

Answer (score 2):

I've got this problem after installing color prompt.
There was:

```bsh
function cd {
    # call builtin cd. change to the new directory
    builtin cd $@
    # call a hook function that can use the new working directory to decide what to do
    color_prompt
}
```

I've fixed it by quoting the argument of builtin `cd`:

```bsh
function cd {
    # call builtin cd. change to the new directory
    builtin cd "$@"
    # call a hook function that can use the new working directory to decide what to do
    color_prompt
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/
```

work fine on my machine .

Answer (score 1):

You may not put colons around the `~` which otherwise will not be dissolved to home real home directory any more.

Use a backslash to escape the space like you tried or escape only the folder containing the space:

```
cd ~/Library/'Application Support'/
```

Your last line works for me. Double-check your spaces, if you still press `[alt]` while typing space, you will enter some protected space not recognized by bash but displayed similarly. Superuser could have converted this, though (just tested using the preview while posting, it does indeed).